# How do I count the number of special characters in a string?

Tags: c, string, special-characters

I'm writing a program that will count the number of lines, words, characters, digits, alphabetic letters, and special characters. So far the program is almost complete, but the special characters are giving me trouble. I used a while loop with if statements to count these characters, with the special characters in an else statement. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

This is the string that I'm using:

Welcome to CIS158.
C and Tux are working hard, are you?
Hopefully you are having fun and learning a new skill.
That being the case, as it should, it is time to say
"Have a Nice Semester!"

Tried an else statement that would increment the special characters.

```
        // Declare a pointer to fopen function to access welcome file
        FILE *fp = fopen("/classes/cis158/cntwlc/welcome", "r");
        char fileName[100];
        char ch;

        int lineCount, charCount, wordCount, abcCount, numCount, speCount;


        lineCount = 0;
        wordCount = 0;
        charCount = 0;
        abcCount  = 0;
        numCount  = 0;
        speCount  = 0;


        gets(fileName);
        //fp = fopen(fileName, "r");


                while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
                        if(ch == '\n')
                                lineCount++;

                        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
                                wordCount++;

                        if(ch != ' ' || ch != '\n')
                                charCount++;

                        if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
                                abcCount++;

                        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                                ++numCount;
                        else
                                speCount++;


                ch++;
                }
                /*if(charCount > 0) {
                        ++lineCount;
                        ++wordCount;
                }*/


        printf("---  Text Statistics:  ---\n\n");
        printf("Lines                %d\n", lineCount);
        printf("Words                %d\n", wordCount);
        printf("Characters           %d\n", charCount);
        printf("Alphabetic           %d\n", abcCount);
        printf("Digits               %d\n", numCount);
        printf("Special              %d\n", speCount);

getchar();
return 0;
        //printf("%20s", &userInput);

}// main
```

These are the expected results:

--- Text Statistics: ---
Lines 5
Words 37
Characters 188
Alphabetic 139
Digits 3
Special 9

This is what I get when I run the program:

---  Text Statistics:  ---

Lines                5
Words                37
Characters           188
Alphabetic           139
Digits               3
Special              185

Comment: right now your specCount counts only non-letters - the else applies only to the last if. Since this is uni assigment that's all I'm gonna say :)

Comment: Advice: run your own testing by reading your own file. Make it contain a very simple test case. When it works well, try another. Only when it looks ok use the final file in the assignment

Answer (score 1):

Your else only matches the if about the numbers. Since that happens, any character that is not a number will count to your special character count.

I suggest the following:

```
// Declare a pointer to fopen function to access welcome file
        FILE *fp = fopen("/classes/cis158/cntwlc/welcome", "r");
        char fileName[100];
        char ch;

        int lineCount, charCount, wordCount, abcCount, numCount, speCount;


        lineCount = 0;
        wordCount = 0;
        charCount = 0;
        abcCount  = 0;
        numCount  = 0;
        speCount  = 0;


        gets(fileName);
        //fp = fopen(fileName, "r");


                while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
                        if(ch == '\n')
                                lineCount++;

                        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
                                wordCount++;

                        if(ch != ' ' || ch != '\n')
                                charCount++;

                        if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
                                abcCount++;

                        else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                                ++numCount;
                        else if(ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')
                                speCount++;


                ch++;
                }
                /*if(charCount > 0) {
                        ++lineCount;
                        ++wordCount;
                }*/


        printf("---  Text Statistics:  ---\n\n");
        printf("Lines                %d\n", lineCount);
        printf("Words                %d\n", wordCount);
        printf("Characters           %d\n", charCount);
        printf("Alphabetic           %d\n", abcCount);
        printf("Digits               %d\n", numCount);
        printf("Special              %d\n", speCount);

getchar();
return 0;
        //printf("%20s", &userInput);

}// main
```

Note that your word count is fallible, but I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Yes, that is true. I prefer to leave this part to be figured out though. I'll edit the answer to clarify that.